# Using TextView on Android Problem

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ListActivity;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.net.Uri;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.AdapterView;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.ListAdapter;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;



public class textfile extends ListActivity {

   // private static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 0;

                private List<String> items = null;

                private File currentDirectory;

                private ArrayAdapter<String> fileList;

                   Intent myIntent = null;

                /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        currentDirectory = new File("/sdcard/myfolder");

        getFiles(currentDirectory.listFiles());

         setContentView(R.layout.main);



    }  



    protected void onListItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, ListView l, View v, int position, long id)

    {

     int selectedRow = (int)id;



       currentDirectory = new File(items.get(selectedRow));

     if(currentDirectory.isDirectory()){

          getFiles(currentDirectory.listFiles());

     } else{

                  //if the selected file is not a directory. get the filename 

           currentDirectory.getPath();

     }

     Intent myIntent = null;



     if(((TextView) v).getText().equals("sdcard/myfolder/anskey.txt")){

         myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), dialog.class);

        }





        startActivity(myIntent);

    }  



    private void getFiles(File[] files){

items = new ArrayList<String>();

     for(File file : files){

     items.add(file.getPath());



     }

       fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, items);

        setListAdapter(fileList);



    }

}
```

In this program i am displaying directory structure display  "sdcard/myfolder" as a list.
now what i want to do is that when i click on  "sdcard/myfolder/anskey.txt"   dialog.class activity should open.

there is no exception but on clicking "sdcard/myfolder/anskey.txt" ,the dialog.class activity is not opening.

Comment: Have you run through the debugger to verify that myIntent isn't null when you call startActivity?

Comment: i think there is some problem in ((TextView) v).getText().please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, your `onListItemClick()` signature is not right. It should be:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

This is the first thing you will want to correct. There could be other issues with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see you assigned the Listener to the listView and I didn't see you declared your class to implement onListItemClickListener as well, so the implementation of onListItemListener is just another method. Follow [this simple tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) to accomplish that